# What does a variable written immediately after "href=" do in html?

Tags: html, url

I can't find a good explanation for this. What is the code after href= doing?

The variable here$ is a URL. The variable result is a directory name.

```
echo "<h1><a href=$here/$result>$result</a></h1>";
```

I understand this is html embedded in php. The echo gives it away.

The question is, what is this:

```
href=$here/$result
```

I do not recognize this code in html.

Answer (score 0):

This is not HTML, but PHP that write an HTML string. You can place [a variable inside double quoted strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). PHP will parse the string and replace the variable by its value.

For example:

```php
$example = "world";
echo "Hello, $example!";
// Outputs: "Hello, world!"
```

Notice that single quoted strings have not this behaviour.

In the case of your question, `$here` and `$result` will be replaced by the variable value, as follow:

```php
$here = "LOCATION"; // just for example purposes
$result = "RESULT"; // just for example purposes
echo "<h1><a href=$here/$result>$result</a></h1>";

// Outputs: "<h1><a href=LOCATION/RESULT>RESULT</a></h1>"
```

It will output a link (`<a>`) where the [`href` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is the address the link points to. If you don't have spaces or `>` symbols in the link, it will work without quotation marks (`"`), but you can as well write it between quotes:

```php
echo "<h1><a href=\"$here/$result\">$result</a></h1>";
// Outputs: "<h1><a href="LOCATION/RESULT">RESULT</a></h1>"
```

The best way I know to understand the `<a>` and its `href` attribute behaviour is to try it in the browser and see it in action by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Usually href is referring to the url of a source, in this case its url + directory, href is necessary to the `<a>` tag which represents a link in HTML